# Automatizing RStudio updates

Tags: upgrade, automation, rstudio

To install RStudio I went to [their website](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/debian-ubuntu/) to grab the `.deb` package and then installed it using the `gdebi` command.

**My question is:**
Do I have to repeat this whole process every time I want to update the software?
Or there is a way to automatize the updating process using `apt-get upgrade` or something similar?
I would also appreciate it if you could comment a bit about automatically upgrading software from external repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two elements here: The *repository* and the *license*.

- Software is distributed from a *repository*. Apt gets software from these repositories. Most of your software comes from the Ubuntu repo. Third parties can run their own repos.
- A Software's *license* must permit redistribution and must be compatible with other licenses in order for the software to be included in the Debian and Ubuntu repositories. Software with an incompatible license must be distributed some other way: A non-Ubuntu repository, a standalone deb or snap, a tarball, etc.

Let's look at three examples of commonly-used software:

- LibreOffice is has a compatible license. It is distributed through the Ubuntu repositories. Updates come through the same repository via Apt.
- Google Chrome has an incompatible license -- Google won't let anybody else distribute their software. Instead, Chrome users add a non-Ubuntu repository. Updates come through the same repository via Apt.
- RStudio Server has an incompatible licence, and NO repository at all. Users must manually download a deb from a webpage. Apt cannot handle updates, since there is no repository.

If you are a paying customer, you should complain to RStudio about their poor Debian/Ubuntu support. A non-Ubuntu repository is simpler to set up and maintain than their web page.